# Locale not switching in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

My Rails App is on rails 4.0.2 and I have a problem switching translations with the `locale` variable and the `params[:locale]` from the url scheme following the official rails [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html). I have a single page website at [my site](https://kryptonet.me).

My routes for Internationalization:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|de/ do
  #my routes here
end
```

My application controller

```
before_filter :set_locale
  def set_locale
     I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
     #Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:locale]= I18n.locale
  end

  # app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  def default_url_options(options = {})
     { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
  end
```

The links to change the locale variables in the view:

```
<%= link_to_unless I18n.locale == :en, "English", locale: :en %>
|
<%= link_to_unless I18n.locale == :de, "Deutsch", locale: :de %>
```

*What happens*: the `locale` variable is set correctly but the translations are not switching. If I remove one of the translation files (currently for english and german) the languages switches to the remaining translation file. When I put back the other translation file and try to switch to it by changing the locale variable it never switches to the other language.

Why is my code not changing the translations?

Comment: I hope you can patch that because Rails 4.0.2 has some serious security problems, and using 4.0.13 is highly recommended. A tool like [Gem Canary](https://gemcanary.com/) can give you a heads up on problems like this before they become trouble.

Comment: I patched the gemset rails 4.0.13, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues and maybe it would be a solution for you:

in `routes.rb` change

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  #your routes here
end
get '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
get '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
```

in `application_controller.rb`

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?
end

def default_url_options(options = {})
  {locale: I18n.locale}
end
```

p.s.

in `config/locales/en.yml` something like this:

```
en:
  languages:
    en: "English"
    de: "Deutsch"
```

and in `config/locales/de.yml` in German

in view

```
<%= link_to_unless_current t('languages.en'), locale: :en %>
|
<%= link_to_unless_current t('languages.de'), locale: :de %>
```

Comment: Your code gives me a output buffer error: `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting :: or '[' or '.'
...k_to_unless_current, "English", locale: :en );@output_buffer...`

Comment: ok! you need to edit `config/locales/en.yml`  `en:
  languages:
    en: "English"
    de: "Deutsch"
`   and in `config/locales/de.yml` in German    than in view:  <%= link_to_unless_current t('languages.en'), locale: :en %>
|
<%= link_to_unless_current t('languages.de'), locale: :de %>

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the constraint on the locale more explicit:

```
scope path: '(:locale)', constraints: { locale: /en|de/ } do
  # routes you want to localize
end
```

Comment: That changed nothing unfortunately.